# Find a basis of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue 3 of the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I'm having some difficulties with this problem. After subtracting 3 from the diagonal, I end up with $$\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&3&3\\0&0&0&0\end{matrix}$$

If I do more reducing, the first row is $$\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\end{matrix}$$

So when I solve for the basis, I get 3,0,1,0 and 3, 0, 0, 1. This isn't correct. What's the correct answer? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try again without changing the order of the rows of the matrix. That’s caused you to make some simple mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract $3$ from the diagonal, you obtain:

$$
A - 3\,\Bbb I_4 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-3&-3\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&3&3\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now remember that the eigenspace of an eigenvalue is defined as the kernel of $A - 3\,\Bbb I_4$; therefore you're looking for all the linearly independent vectors $\mathbf v$ such that $(A - 3\,\Bbb I_4)\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$.

You can then solve the whole linear system **or** *take a closer look at the matrix*.

For example, the second column is the zero vector. Then if $\mathbf v = (0,1,0,0)^T$ then you have $(A - 3\,\Bbb I_4)\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$: note that the $1$ in $\mathbf v$ is on the second entry.

The matrix $A - 3\,\Bbb I_4$ has rank two though, so there must be another vector in the eigenspace; to prove that the rank is two, you don't need to do any calculations. Again, look at the matrix: the first row is a linear combination of the second and the third (($-1$) * second + ($-1$) * third = first ), the fourth row is zero and the second and the third are obviously linearly independent (they are not multiples).

To find the last vector, let's take a last look at the matrix; the fourth and the third column are equal. What happens is we consider $\mathbf v = (0,0,1,-1)^T$? If we calculate $(A - 3\,\Bbb I_4)\mathbf v$, that vector sums the third column with the opposite of the fourth column, and again you obtain $\mathbf 0$. Obviously, $(0,1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1,-1)^T$ are linearly independent (they are not multiples).

Finally, the eigenspace of $3$ for $A$ is $\langle(0\ 1\ 0\ 0)^T,(0\ 0\ 1\ -1)^T\rangle$.

I wrrote down what I'm grateful my teachers taught me about solving linear systems with little calculations. This procedure may seem difficult in the beginning, but once you learn it, linear systems like these are really definitely easier to solve.